# LINQ - left outer join - a better way

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have 2 tables that I need to get data from...Rooms and Address.  The Rooms table has an AddressID field in it but it can be null, so the relationship is 0 to 1.  I've been trying to write a LINQ statement that will return a specific Room AND the Address information if it exists.  My model is defined as so:

```
public partial class Room
{
    public Room()
    {
        this.Address = new HashSet<Address>();
    }

    public int RoomID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AddressID { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Address { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to use the .Include("Address") on the linq statement but it didn't work and I believe it's caused by the Join statement (which I read, once it's used, it silently drops the Include).

Here's an ugly way around it but I know there's a better way:

```
var csdDB = new CSDContext(CustomerCode);

IList<Room> rooms = (from r in csdDB.Rooms
                        join sr in csdDB.SiteRooms
                            on r.RoomID equals sr.RoomID
                        where sr.SiteID == id
                        orderby r.RoomName
                        select r).ToList<Room>();

int? addressID = rooms.FirstOrDefault<Room>().AddressID;

if (addressID != null)
{
    IList<Address> address = (from a in csdDB.Addresses
                                where a.AddressID == addressID
                                select a).ToList<Address>();

    rooms.FirstOrDefault<Room>().Address = address;
}
```

I tried to do the filtering directly on the results:

```
IList<Address> address = (from a in csdDB.Addresses
                            where a.AddressID == rooms.FirstOrDefault().AddressID
                            select a).ToList<Address>();
```

But it throws an error:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Models.CSD.Room'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

Any suggestions on how to make this cleaner/better is appreciated!

Comment: You said `Room` has 0-1 relationship with `Address`, then why does `Room` have `ICollection<Address>`?

Comment: Sorry for that....this is something we are looking to expand on....meaning, eventually, allowing Rooms to have 0 to many addresses.

Comment: Then you don't need `Nullable<int> AddressID`. I think it's confusing EF. The Address table should have a `RoomID` instead.

Comment: Understood, but I can't make those changes at this time.  Our Address table is used by other tables (Locations, Companies, etc.) and adding that field would take some time.

Comment: Try changing the Address property to `public virtual Address Address { get; set; }` and check if it works

Comment: @SidharthMudgal - I tried your suggestions but unfortunately it didn't work.  It throws the same error as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporating a left-join in LINQ might look something like this:

```
var results = (from r in csdDB.Rooms
               join sr in csdDB.SiteRooms
                   on r.RoomID equals sr.RoomID && sr.SiteID equals id
               join addr in csdDB.Addresses
                   on r.AddressID equals addr.AddressID into roomAddrs
               from roomAddr in roomAddrs.DefaultIfEmpty(new Address())
               select new 
               {
                   Room = r,
                   Address = roomAddr
               }
```